# WebElement not identified in selenium c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium

Here is the HTML which i am using

```html
        <div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Show Alert" ng-click="questions.getIrMessage()" 
data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="questions.showIrGrid()" data-dismiss="modal">Edit</button>
</div>
```

I am trying to find 'Edit' button using the below line of code

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")]
 public IWebElement btnEdit;
```

I am getting No Element found exception when i try to use this property.

When i expand btnEdit property in the code, i can see that the 'Displayed' property is false and also text property is empty  [Property image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6XHd.png)

Please find the attached image.

But when i try to find 'confirm' button there are no issues and i am able to find the webelement.

What is the reason for not getting the button webelemnt.Thank you in advance

Comment: is Displayed property same for confirm button ?

Comment: After the page loads in the browser, run `$x("//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]").length` in the dev console. Does it return > 0? Look at the HTML of the loaded page, can you see the element and why it might be hidden? You will likely need to post a link to the page or more relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium simulates user actions. Your element is not visible to the user (display=none), so Selenium can't read it either.

You can find hidden elements using:

```
IList<IWebElement> hidden = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("button[style=display:none]"));
```

You should find your element in this list.

Comment: Where do you see that the button is hidden in the HTML provided? Even if it was, your code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your reply.There are two elements with the same name, that is the reason for confusion.Actually i want the second one.Below is the code i used to click the button i want
`SeleniumWrapper.driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]"))[1].Click();`